# installing SQL Server 2008 R2 with advance options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install the SQL Server 2008 R2. I have uninstalled the previous versions of SQL Server from my machine and also deleted SQL Server folder from c:\Program Files.I select New installation or ad features to SQL installation, when setup runs, accept the license, but after setup supported files (see attached image), setup ends. Whats wrong with it. How can I install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with advance options on my machine.

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: Where's the Image ??

Comment: Please see the image now

Comment: What do you mean "setup ends"? What do you see exactly *after* the above Setup Support Files finishes?

Comment: @Aaron, screen disappears

Comment: Doesn't sound very common. Are you closing the background window (SQL Server Installation Center)? Have you reviewed the setup logs as Josh suggested?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need: [How to: View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx)

Look through there and if you have more questions post the error descriptions back to here.